# Movement controls (2D scene)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am having an issue with my movement code I am writing for a top down RPG in 2D. Forgive my lack of knowledge but I have only recently had to learn how to code and this is my first attempt at movement controls. The desired result is to have two input methods; the controller and keyboard. I want to have them separate so when you are using the controller you cannot use the keyboard and vice-versa. Here is the code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{   

    public float Speed = 1;
    private float deadZone = 0.25f;    

    // START - Use this for initialization
    void Start () {}

    // UPDATE is called once per frame - Using deadZone to compensate for faulty controllers etc.... Using options for controller true or false to switch between keyboard and controller input.
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {

        Vector2 stickInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        if ( Options.useController == true)
        {
            if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                stickInput = Vector2.zero;
            }
            else if ( stickInput.magnitude < deadZone)
            {
                stickInput = Vector2.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

        }

        //Here is keyboard input - this is working great.
        else if ( Options.useController == false)
        {
            if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(-1f,1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime;  
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(1f,1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(1f,-1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(-1f,-1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(0f,1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(1f,0f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(0f,-1f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }
            else if  ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                stickInput = new Vector2(-1f,0f);
                stickInput.Normalize();
                rigidbody2D.velocity = stickInput * Speed * Time.deltaTime; 
            }       
        }




    }
}
```

The issue arrives when the top loop is executing. I want movement from the keys to be null when `useController` is equal to true. It works great as long as the key is held down, but as soon as you release the key (A, D, S, W) it exits the if statement and the player is moved by the remaining `GetAxis` value.

I have to use `GetAxis` for the controller input in this loop and unfortunately Unity automatically grabs values from the keys. Is there a way I can not only limit the velocity to 0 but also make sure that when the key is released the `GetAxis` value also becomes 0.

Comment: Just a (really quick) suggestion: have you tried using GetKeyDown() instead of GetKey()? Don't know if it could be the solution, by the way...

Comment: I might also try this to see if it changes anything. It would make sense that on key down the velocity and GetAxis is set. Good idea!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem, good idea though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a rigidbody2d attached to the object you want to move using rigidbody2d.velocity. But, it's not a good idea to do that every frame. Instead, you could use transform.translate, or if you want to keep the physics simulation by using the rigidbodies, use rigidbody2d.addforce.

Also, in Edit > Project Settings > Input make sure you remove the WSAD keys from the axes.

Your code should look more something like this

```
void FixedUpdate () 
{

    if (Options.useController)
    {
        // if the controller is enabled do this stuff
        Vector2 stickInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }
    else
    {
        // else if the controller is not enabled, do this stuff.
        stickinput = new Vector2(0, 0);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)
            stickinput += new Vector2(0, 1);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)
            stickinput += new Vector2(0, -1);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)
            stickinput += new Vector2(-1, 0);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)
            stickinput += new Vector2(1, 0);
        /* can have code like:
         * if (stickinput.x > 0)
         *     animator.crossfade("rightAnimation", 0f);
         * else if (stickinput.x < 0)
         *     animator.crossfade("leftanimation", 0f);
         * else
         *     animator.crossfade("standinganimation", 0f);
         */
    }

        transform.Translate(((stickinput.magnitude > 1) ? stickinput.normalized : stickinput) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);

        // or use the one commented out below
        // rigidbody2D.AddForce(((stickinput.magnitude > 1) ? stickinput.normalized : stickinput) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);


}
```

Notice I didn't use else if's. If someone holds W and S, it adds to 0 for the y component. I chose Space.Self for local translation, but you could use Space.World to move it in relation to the global axes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this and see what I get. I might have to edit the code that also controls the animation state so that everything is copacetic, but this looks like a good start. Thank you again!

Comment: I tried to implement the above code. It works great if I don't care that the player can use the keys when the controller is enabled, but I do. I want them to have to choose between either. Meaning if the controller is enabled, then the keys are disabled. With this implemented there is nothing stopping the user from using the keys when the controller is enabled. Thus the controls for the keys feel floaty and could cause confusion. It was a good try though!

Comment: Apparently I was going do something a bit different and forgot to change it or something. I changed if (!Options.useController) to if (Options.useController) Also, make sure you changed your input settings under project settings. This will stop the player from using the keys when the controller's enabled.

Comment: Changed the answer to include an example of changing the animation state based on this input scheme. Also, stickinput should probably be declared outside of FixedUpdate.

Comment: I must have missed you stating that I had to remove WSAD from the input manager in the first post. This was literally the only thing I had to do achieve the goal I had in mind. I could definitely clean the code up to match yours as well, for house keeping. Thank you very much for the answer!